# Notation for joins/meets in lattice theory

Tags: notation, soft-question, lattice-orders

Most often I see $\lor$ and $\land$ used for the join and meet operations respectively in a lattice, however what I am writing makes concurrent use of both symbolic logic and a particular lattice, thus I am already using these operations to express logical conjunction/disjunction and am unsure what to use for the joins/meets. For example I don't want to use $\cup$ and $\cap$ since I think this might cause confusion with sets or enable some unconscious error where I treat them like their set counter parts i.e. I might accidentally distribute them over each other despite not dealing with a distributive lattice, likewise for similar reasons I'd rather not use $\sqcup$ and $\sqcap$ as I often use the latter for 'disjoint' unions. So with all of that in mind what are some standard alternatives to these that I could use for joins/meets in a lattice?

Comment: $\Cup$ and $\Cap$ maybe? I doubt there's a great choice if you need to avoid all three types of symbols you mentioned.

Comment: i just need somthing meet/join symbols other then $\lor,\land,\cup,\cap,\sqcup$

Comment: In the Boolean algebra setting, it is also common to use additive and multiplicative notation for join and meet, respectively. I don't remember now a reference, but I think that in ancient Lattice Theory papers this was also common, for some authors. Perhaps the reason was just that those symbols were more easily accessed. Personally, I think it looks weird, specially when dealing with equalities in which both operations appear; for example, one distributivity law would be $$x(y+z)=xy+xz,$$ which looks OK, but the other equivalent one, $$x+yz=(x+y)(x+z),$$ not really.

Comment: As @amrsa suggests, old lattice theorists used + for join and * or $\cdot$ for meet.  I recommend using those since they were standard well before $\vee$ and $\wedge$ came into fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Supremum and infimum, or greatest lower bound and least upper bound.

$$a\vee b=\sup(a,b)=\text{lub}(a,b)$$

$$a\wedge b=\inf(a,b)=\text{glb}(a,b)$$